# Send and receive events between two javascript files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I am trying to communicate between two javascript files using EventEmitter, but I am struggling to get it working in both directions.

I have server.js:

```
let api = require('./api')

// Does not work
api.on("yo", data => {
    console.log(data)
})

// Works
api.emit("ready", "Server ready")
```

and api.js:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')
let api = new EventEmitter()

// Works
api.on("ready", data => {
    console.log(data)
})

// Does not work
api.emit("yo", "yo yo")

module.exports = api
```

`server.js` is able to emit events to `api.js`, but not the other way around. I have tried module.exports and requiring both files in each other respectively at the same time, but that is causing errors.

How can I accomplish two-way emits/ons between these two files?

Answer (score 1):

At first api.js is initialized and at that moment nobody is subscribed on 'yo' event yet. So you shouldn't emit any events during any module initialization at all. Try to emit events afterwards somehow.

**OR** you can move all subscribing stuff into another module in which you can emit any event after all subscriptions are done.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm still quite confused. Ultimately, I want api.js to be able to receive and send events to any number of other modules including server.js.

Comment: But you call `api.emit("yo", "yo yo")` in api.js as well while api.js is initialized. Try to emit events later after all modules are already initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Because when we import api.js in the top of server.js we add its contents before server.js contents.

So, we emit the "yo" event before adding the Event Listener as follows:

```
    api.emit("yo", "yo yo") 
    ... 
  // this does not work
    api.on("yo", data => {
            console.log(data)
    })
```

If we for example wait for 1 second till the module initialization gets finished as Anatoly suggested. It would work as follows:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      // this works
        api.emit("yo", "yo yo")
    }, 1000)
```